Создание панели активных файлов в Qt-Designer
Не давно начал изучать PyQt при написание программы и столкнулся с вопросом: 
Как сделать список активных файлов или проектов?
Когда вы открываете PyCharm, Sublime Text или даже Блокнот, то сверху можно увидеть список файлов, которые сейчас открыты для работы.
Можно ли реализовать такое с помощью PyQt и если можно, то как?

Такой виджет должен открываться, закрываться и отображать какие-либо элементы программы внутри себя

UPD:
Что есть на данный момент:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <author>Dynamic Software, Dynamic Aerospace</author>
 <class>IIC</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="IIC">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>IIC - (демо версия)</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="File">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Файл</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="New"/>
    <addaction name="Open"/>
    <addaction name="RecentFile"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="Close"/>
    <addaction name="CloseAll"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="Save"/>
    <addaction name="SaveAs"/>
    <addaction name="Export"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="Preview"/>
    <addaction name="Print"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="Send"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="InformationDocument"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="Exit"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="Edit">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Правка</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="Undo"/>
    <addaction name="Redo"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="RepeatLastCommand"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="Cut"/>
    <addaction name="Copy"/>
    <addaction name="Paste"/>
    <addaction name="Delete"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="Scale"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="Settings">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Настройки</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="RestoreLicenses"/>
    <addaction name="ReceiveLicensesIIC"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="Parameters"/>
    <addaction name="LoadParameters"/>
    <addaction name="SaveParameters"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="Apps">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Приложения</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="AddApps"/>
    <addaction name="Configurator"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="Window">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Окно</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="CloseCurrentWindow"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="Help">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Справка</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="Content"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="TrainingMaterials"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="IICOnInternet"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="LicenseAgreement"/>
    <addaction name="AboutProgram"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="Decoration">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Оформление</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="StyleLibrary"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="CreateReport"/>
    <addaction name="EditTemplateReport"/>
    <addaction name="CreateTemplateReport"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="Analysis">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Анализ</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="AnalysisInjector"/>
    <addaction name="OptimizationInjector"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="CustomExpressions"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="File"/>
   <addaction name="Edit"/>
   <addaction name="Analysis"/>
   <addaction name="Decoration"/>
   <addaction name="Settings"/>
   <addaction name="Apps"/>
   <addaction name="Window"/>
   <addaction name="Help"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="New">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Новый</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Open">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Открыть</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="RecentFile">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Последние файлы</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Save">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Сохранить</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="SaveAs">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Сохранить как</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_PDF">
   <property name="text">
    <string>.PDF</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_TXT">
   <property name="text">
    <string>.TXT</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Export">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Экспортировать</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Print">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Печать</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Exit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Выход</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Undo">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Отменить</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Redo">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Повторить</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Cut">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Вырезать</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Copy">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Копировать</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Paste">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Вставить</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_6">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Дублировать</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Delete">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Удалить</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Scale">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Масштабировать</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="RestoreLicenses">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Восстановить лицензии</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="ReceiveLicensesIIC">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Получить лицензию на IIC</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Parameters">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Параметры</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="LoadParameters">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Загрузить параметры</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="SaveParameters">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Сохранить параметры</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="AddApps">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Добавить приложение</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Configurator">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Конфигуратор</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="CloseCurrentWindow">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Закрыть текущую вкладку</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Content">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Содержание</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="TrainingMaterials">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Обучающие материалы</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="IICOnInternet">
   <property name="text">
    <string>IIC в интернете</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="LicenseAgreement">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Лицензионное соглашение</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="AboutProgram">
   <property name="text">
    <string>О программе</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="InformationDocument">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Информация о документе</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Send">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Отправить</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Close">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Закрыть</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="CloseAll">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Закрыть все документы</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="Preview">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Предварительный просмотр</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="RepeatLastCommand">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Повторить последнюю команду</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="StyleLibrary">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Библиотека стилей</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="CreateReport">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Создать отчет</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="EditTemplateReport">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Редактировать шаблон отчета</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="CreateTemplateReport">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Создать шаблон отчета</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="AnalysisInjector">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Анализ форсунки</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="OptimizationInjector">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Оптимизация форсунки</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="CustomExpressions">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Пользовательские выражения</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>

Скриншот для наглядности:


dynamic.aerospace.inc, Вы начали изучать PyQt,
а создание панели активных файлов
хотите сделать в Qt Designer?
И тутже спрашиваете, можно ли реализовать такое с помощью PyQt.
Вы хотите сделать IDE с использованием PyQt?
Покажите что вы уже написали.

это называется "вкладки" типа https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTabWidget.html + логика отображения

@S.Nick извиняюсь за долгий ответ, добавил что уже есть сейчас. Хочу реализовать примерно тоже самое. Может что-то похожее на ответ ganz

Не очень уверен что правильно понял вас, но попробуйте проверить возможный вариант:

Конвертируем вашу форму .ui в .py:
pyuic5 q1592407.ui -o q1592407_ui.py -x

Выполнить main.py:


.
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from q1592407_ui import Ui_IIC


lineBarColor       = QColor(53, 53, 53)       
lineHighlightColor = QColor('#00FF04')   


class NumberBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.editor = parent
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.editor.blockCountChanged.connect(self.update_width)
        self.editor.updateRequest.connect(self.update_on_scroll)
        self.update_width('001')   

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        print("\n - class NumberBar(): \n\tdef mousePressEvent():")

    def update_on_scroll(self, rect, scroll):
        if self.isVisible():
            if scroll:
                self.scroll(0, scroll)
            else:
                self.update()

    def update_width(self, string):
        width = self.fontMetrics().width(str(string)) + 10
        if self.width() != width:
            self.setFixedWidth(width)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.isVisible():
            block   = self.editor.firstVisibleBlock()
            height  = self.fontMetrics().height()
            number  = block.blockNumber()
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.fillRect(event.rect(), lineBarColor)
            painter.setPen(Qt.white)                       
            painter.drawRect(
                0, 0, 
                event.rect().width() - 1, 
                event.rect().height() - 1)
            font = painter.font()

            current_block = self.editor.textCursor().block().blockNumber() + 1

            while block.isValid():
                block_geometry = self.editor.blockBoundingGeometry(block)
                offset = self.editor.contentOffset()
                block_top = block_geometry.translated(offset).top()
                number += 1

                rect = QRect(0, block_top, self.width() - 5, height)

                if number == current_block:
                    font.setBold(True)
                else:
                    font.setBold(False)

                painter.setFont(font)
                painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignRight, '%i' % number)

                if block_top > event.rect().bottom():
                    break

                block = block.next()
            painter.end()
            

class Content(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(Content, self).__init__()
        self.editor = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.editor.setPlainText(text)
        self.hbox    = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.numbers = NumberBar(self.editor)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.numbers)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.editor)
        

class TabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
  
    def tabRemoved(self, index):
        print(f"\n вкладка удалена из индекса позиции -> {index}")

    def tabInserted(self, index):
        print(f"\n Новая вкладка была добавлена или вставлена "
            f"в индекс позиции -> {index}")
    

class MyTableWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = TabWidget()                  
        self.tabs.resize(300, 200)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)

    def addtab(self, content, fileName):
        self.tabs.addTab(Content(str(content)), str(fileName))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_IIC):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tabs = MyTableWidget()
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

        self.Open.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
        self.New.triggered.connect(self.new)

    def new(self):
        self.tabs.addtab('', 'new_file_name.txt')                     

    def openFile(self):                                   
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        filenames, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
            self, 'Open a file', '',
            'Python Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)',
            options=options
        )
        if filenames:
            for filename in filenames:
                with open(filename, 'r+') as file_o:
                    try: 
                        text = file_o.read()
                        self.tabs.addtab(text, filename)      
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("Error: filename=`{}`, `{}` ".format( filename, str(e)))
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())







это точно нужно! А можно сделать так, чтобы при создании нового файла открывалась такая новая вкладка и при этом содержала несколько кнопок или других блоков?

и можете добавить небольшие комментарии коду или добавить источники где можно прочитать про создание такого виджета? За ранее спасибо)

@dynamic.aerospace.inc пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour  Вам надо хорошо проработать данный вариант кода, если после изучения вам будет что-то конкретное не понятно - спросите. Все можно сделать. но вы должны попробовать сделать ваши задумки самостоятельно. Если что-то не будет получаться - зададите новый вопрос, приведете ваш код  и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

хорошо, большое спасибо за помощь!
